# ¿Cómo obtener un valor de un JSON en Java?

Tags: java, json, jsonobject, jsonarray, geojson

Buen día compañeros, espero me puedan entender y ayudar a realizar lo siguiente: 
mando el siguiente JSON desde la ulr {nombre:"Juan",preferencias:["Leer","Cantar"]}, lo que yo quiero hacer es obtener los valores de **"preferencias"**, el nombre lo obtengo de la siguiente forma sin ningún problema:

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject myJson = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(json-request);
System.out.println(myJson.get("nombre").getAsString());
```

Entonces para obtener el valor de preferencia no se si usar un JsonArray o un JsonObject y luego pasarlo a un Array convencional. Aqui esta la forma como lo he estado haciendo sin éxito:

```
JsonArray datos = myJson.getAsJsonArray("nom_geo");
            for (int i = 0; i < datos.size(); i++) {
               System.out.println(""+datos.get(1).toString());
```

Espero me puedan ayudar por favor, la forma en que envió los datos de prueba es la siguiente:

```
http://localhost:8080/ServiciosRestCNG/webresources/getnames/{nombre:"Juan",,preferencias:["Leer","Cantar"]}
```

Saludos cordiales!

Answer (score 1):

La forma correcta es convertirlo a JsonArray así como lo has hecho el problema es que accediste a un elemento que no existe "nom_geo" no existe en tu json el nombre del array es "preferencias " Ejemplo.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json = "{nombre:\"Juan\",preferencias:[\"Leer\",\"Cantar\"]}";
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonObject myJson = (JsonObject) jsonParser.parse(json);

    System.out.println("Nombre: "+myJson.get("nombre").getAsString());

    //se define JsonArray -> se obtiene preferencias de myJson
    JsonArray preferencias = myJson.getAsJsonArray("preferencias");
    //puedes recorrer con un for
    for (int i = 0; i < preferencias.size(); i++) {
        System.err.println("preferencias->"+preferencias.get(i).toString());
    }


}
```

Espero Haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Emilio Garcia, Ahora guardo ese atributo como ArrayJson  y ya pude obtenerlo correctamente para poder recorrer su valores, saludos mi estimado...